# Facebook has deprecated the Open Graph Objects and Stories What are alternatives?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, deep-linking, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-invite-friends

As I am observing from some time, Facebook has started to phase out quite allot of usable features from their Platform. The Open Graph Custom Stories (Object & Actions) Support is one of them. They even restricted usage of score Api. Which means we can't use the score API if we are not using publish_actions for something more than just score API. They also have deprecated the App Invites. 
My main concern is with the Open Graph Objects. As I am making a game where I need to send and receive Lives/ Gems or other In game Items. How many of the popular games are using in app gifting as the Open Graph object creation isn't possible now. The Open Graph Section on the Left of Facebook Developer console is also not available in new games. Please suggest where I can find it ? I am not talking about the Custom Open Graph, I am not even able to see the Predefined Open Graph Objects which Facebook Said that they still are supporting.